# Reactive merging multiple observables to one observable with boolean

Tags: c#, reactive, reactiveui, avaloniaui

how can i do merging observables.

```
IObservable<bool> addCommandIsExecutingObservable = this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.AddCommand.IsExecuting).StartWith(false).Select(x => x);
IObservable<bool> cleanCommandIsExecutingObservable = this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.CleanCommand.IsExecuting).StartWith(false).Select(x => x);
IObservable<bool> tagIsSuitableObservable = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Tag).StartWith(string.Empty).Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && x.Length >= 3);
IObservable<bool> warehouseBarcodeIsSuitableObservable = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.WarehouseBarcode).StartWith(0).Select(x => x > 0);
IObservable<bool> stockAmountIsSuitableObservable = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.StockAmount).StartWith(0).Select(x => x > 0);
IObservable<bool> subcategoryIdIsSuiableObservable = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SubcategorySearchingFormViewModel.Id).StartWith(0).Select(x => x > 0);
```

I am trying with that code

```
IObservable<bool> addCommandCanExecute = Observable.Merge(addCommandIsExecutingObservable.Select(x => !x), cleanCommandIsExecutingObservable.Select(x => !x), tagIsSuitableObservable, warehouseBarcodeIsSuitableObservable, stockAmountIsSuitableObservable, subcategoryIdIsSuiableObservable);
```

I want to if all observables is true then return true, if one observable false then return the false.

Comment: Look into CombineLatest.

Comment: Thank you. I solved

Comment: Here is a list of operators that exist in Rx ecosystems.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html